# Python Sqlite3-Program Breaking After Calling execute- SELECT Query

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Select query is not executing in python3-sqlite3, instead my program breaks right after that statement. My code is running fine with no errors but whenever i click on radio button (in GUI) which calls a function containing above execute statement ,it breaks.

I'm new to sqlite3 and even python3, I'm working on my first python project which is built using above 2 and Qt designer, after converting my code from qtdesigner i added necessary codes, here's MyCricket.py code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QRadioButton, QFrame, QMessageBox)
from DialogBox2 import Ui_Dialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QRect

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self,MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(730, 562)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 101, 21))  
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")     
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 681, 61))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_8.setFont(font)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_8)
        self.l1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.l1.setFont(font)
        self.l1.setObjectName("l1")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.l1)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_9.setFont(font)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_9)
        self.l2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.l2.setFont(font)
        self.l2.setObjectName("l2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.l2)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.l3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.l3.setFont(font)
        self.l3.setObjectName("l3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.l3)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.l4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.l4.setFont(font)
        self.l4.setObjectName("l4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.l4)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 130, 681, 51))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_13.setFont(font)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_13)
        self.l5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.l5.setFont(font)
        self.l5.setObjectName("l5")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.l5)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_11.setFont(font)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_11)
        self.l6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.l6.setFont(font)
        self.l6.setObjectName("l6")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.l6)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.listW1 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listW1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 230, 261, 271))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.listW1.setFont(font)
        self.listW1.setObjectName("listW1")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listW2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listW2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 230, 281, 271))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.listW2.setFont(font)
        self.listW2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.listW2.setObjectName("listW2")       
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 190, 261, 51))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.rb1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.rb1.setObjectName("rb1")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.rb1)
        self.rb2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.rb2.setObjectName("rb2")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.rb2)
        self.rb3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.rb3.setObjectName("rb3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.rb3)
        self.rb4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.rb4.setObjectName("rb4")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.rb4)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 190, 281, 51))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_4)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_14.setFont(font)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_14)
        self.l7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_4)
        self.l7.setObjectName("l7")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.l7)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem3)
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_16.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 320, 21, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_16.setFont(font)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 730, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuManage_Teams = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuManage_Teams.setObjectName("menuManage_Teams")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionNEW_Team = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNEW_Team.setObjectName("actionNEW_Team")
        self.actionOPEN_Team = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOPEN_Team.setObjectName("actionOPEN_Team")
        self.actionSAVE_Team = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSAVE_Team.setObjectName("actionSAVE_Team")
        self.actionEVALUATE_Team = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionEVALUATE_Team.setObjectName("actionEVALUATE_Team")


        #self.actionEVALUATE_Team.triggered.connect(self.OpenWindow)


        self.menuManage_Teams.addAction(self.actionNEW_Team)
        self.menuManage_Teams.addSeparator()
        self.menuManage_Teams.addAction(self.actionOPEN_Team)
        self.menuManage_Teams.addSeparator()
        self.menuManage_Teams.addAction(self.actionSAVE_Team)
        self.menuManage_Teams.addSeparator()
        self.menuManage_Teams.addAction(self.actionEVALUATE_Team)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuManage_Teams.menuAction())

        #self.listW1.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.removelist1)
        #self.listW2.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.removelist2)

        self.rb1.clicked.connect(self.fillList)
        self.rb2.clicked.connect(self.fillList)
        self.rb3.clicked.connect(self.fillList)
        self.rb4.clicked.connect(self.fillList)

        #self.menuManage_Teams.triggered[QtWidgets.QAction].connect(self.menu)

        self.bat=0
        self.bwl=0
        self.ar=0
        self.wk=0
        self.avl=1000
        self.used=0

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Fantasy Cricket Game"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Your Selections"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Batsmen(BAT)"))
        self.l1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" color:#00aa00;\">##</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Bowlers(BOW)"))
        self.l2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" color:#00aa00;\">##</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Allrounders(AR)"))
        self.l3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" color:#00aa00;\">##</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Wicket-keeper(WK)"))
        self.l4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" color:#00aa00;\">##</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Points Available"))
        self.l5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" color:#00aa00;\">####</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Points Used"))
        self.l6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" color:#00aa00;\">####</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.rb1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "BAT"))
        self.rb2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "BOW"))
        self.rb3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "AR"))
        self.rb4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "WK"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Team Name"))
        self.l7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" color:#00aa00;\">Displayed Here</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ">"))
        self.menuManage_Teams.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Manage Teams"))
        self.actionNEW_Team.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "NEW Team"))
        self.actionOPEN_Team.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OPEN Team"))
        self.actionSAVE_Team.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SAVE Team"))
        self.actionEVALUATE_Team.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "EVALUATE Team"))

    def fillList(self):
        curcricket = MyCricket.cursor()

        if self.rb1.isChecked(): # Only showing for radiobutton1 code for rest buttons are similar.
            print("HELP")
            curcricket.execute("SELECT * FROM Stats WHERE Ctg = BAT;") # This is breaking my code, i added 2 print 'help' to check this breaking.
            print("HELP")
            BT = curcricket.fetchall()
            self.listW1.clear()
            for i in range(len(BT)):
                item1 = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(BT[i][0])
                font = QtGui.QFont()
                font.setFamily("Comic Sans MS")
                font.setPointSize(10)
                font.setBold(True)
                font.setWeight(75)
                item1.setFont(font)
                self.listW1.addItem(item1)
        curcricket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sqlite3
    MyCricket=sqlite3.connect('MyCricket.db')
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My application contains Qradiobuttons(BAT,BWL,AR,WK) and QlistWidgets
Whenever radio buttons are clicked i want my list widget to be filled with my Stats Table (only column 1 i.e "Player"(player-name) of particular Category column 7 i.e "Ctg" (BAT,BWL..) ) of database MyCricket.db. Im stuck with this problem and im not able to proceed futher. I wasted a lot of time searching over internet but didnt find a soln to this,I'm still researching so if anyone has the answer, please let me know.

Comment: I don't use PyQt, but generally on Qt/C++, one doesn't need to modify the code auto-generated by QtDesigner... Usually one calls it from the `MainWindow` class, not from `Ui_*`.

Comment: @TrebledJ Its completely fine to modify code generated by Qt designer(i have tried it before too), we make modules to call them in main program for just simplicity (mostly in cases involving long lines of codes)

Comment: @S.Nick I have added whole setupUi class(spaces in btw indicate addition of statements in code) ,theres no error in this code it runs fine but breaks in the execute statement (Whenever radio button is clicked)in fillList method...

Comment: @rohit523 share your MyCricket.db

Comment: @eyllanesc https://github.com/rohit523/project.git , sorry for uplaoding late.. i was a little busy today...and im also new to github so was checking how to share files..please let me know if you find the answer, thanks!

Comment: @rohit523 change`curcricket.execute("SELECT * FROM Stats WHERE Ctg = BAT;")` to `curcricket.execute("SELECT * FROM Stats WHERE Ctg = 'BAT';")`

Comment: @eyllanesc THANK YOU SOO MUCH! It was just a silly mistake i did and i was wondering for soo long >.<